# Django: dynamic model fields and migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have problems understanding how django's model fields work. What I want to achieve is something like a PriceField (DecimalField), that dynamically creates/injects another model field, let's say a currency (CharField) field.

I have read an interesing blog posts about this topic at https://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/08/fuzzydates-or-one-django-model-field-multiple-database-columns/. I think (and hope) that I've understood the core messages of the articles. But as most of them are a little bit outdated, I don't know if they are still valid for current django versions and my below code.

I use `Django 1.11.4`, `Python 3.6.2`, and a clean app created with `./manage.py startapp testing`. The code in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals


_currency_field_name = lambda name: '{}_extension'.format(name)


class PriceField(models.DecimalField):

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        # add the extra currency field (CharField) to the class
        if not cls._meta.abstract:
            currency_field = models.CharField(
                max_length=3, 
                editable=False,
                null=True, 
                blank=True
            )
            cls.add_to_class(_currency_field_name(name), currency_field)
        # add the original price field (DecimalField) to the class
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name)

        # TODO: set the descriptor
        # setattr(cls, self.name, FooDescriptor(self))


class FooModel(models.Model):

    price = PriceField('agrhhhhh', decimal_places=3, max_digits=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

The problems come if I try to create migrations for that models. If executing `python manage.py makemigrations` following message is shown:

```
Migrations for 'testing':
  testing/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model FooModel
```

Migration file `0001_initial.py` has the following content:

```
# Generated by Django 1.11.4 on 2017-09-11 18:02
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import testing.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='FooModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('price', testing.models.PriceField(blank=True, decimal_places=3, max_digits=10, null=True, verbose_name='agrhhhhh')),
                ('price_extension', models.CharField(blank=True, editable=False, max_length=3, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

For me this looks OK so far. But if I then execute **`./manage.py migrate testing`**, django shouts:

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: testing
Running migrations:
Applying testing.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: price_extension
```

Why does it error out on a **duplicate column name: price_extension**, when there is only one such field defined in the migrations file? Where does this duplicate field come from and is there a fix for this situation? Thanks!

### Edit 1

This exception not only happens with an already existing database but also when I start with an empty database from scratch (deleting SQLite file). After the migrate command failed this is the structure of the DB:

```
./manage.py dbshell
sqlite> .tables
django_migrations
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "app" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "applied" datetime NOT NULL);
sqlite> select * from django_migrations;
sqlite>
```

And full stacktrace:

```
./manage.py migrate testing
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: testing
Running migrations:
  Applying testing.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: price_extension

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cachalot/monkey_patch.py", line 113, in inner
    out = original(cursor, sql, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/stockmanagement-3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: duplicate column name: price_extension
```

### Edit 2

A git repository with the above code can be found under: https://github.com/hetsch/django_testing. This error happens also if one clones this repository (clean project without any DB), calls `makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Comment: You may have already created that table in the db with a column of that name. Can you show me the existing tables in the db and existing schema of the `foomodel` table if it exists? You can inspect the db using the `manage.py db_shell` command.

Comment: I've added some information about the database. The strange thing is that this exception also happens on freshly created database where no `foomodel` table exists.

Comment: I've added the full exception message. Hope this helps.

Comment: try dropping the db AND the migrations, than recreating the migrations and submitting it

Comment: Yes, I've tried that many times. No success so far. I've created a new sample project on github (**no ìnitial DB, no migrations**). `https://github.com/hetsch/django_testing`. If one clones it, calls `makemigrations` and `migrate`, the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

According to Django ticket #22555 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22555, this method of adding fields is not officially supported. Nonetheless, I made it work with the following simple fix:

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
    # add the extra currency field (CharField) to the class
    # and prevent adding another field instance if the
    # field was allready attached.
    if not cls._meta.abstract and not hasattr(cls, _currency_field_name(name)):
        currency_field = models.CharField(
            max_length=3, 
            editable=False,
            null=True, 
            blank=True
        )
        cls.add_to_class(_currency_field_name(name), currency_field)
```

Comment: Use `inspect.getattr_static()` instead of `hasattr()` function. The last one will call `getattr()` function. It can lead to an error if you check for a descriptor object that raise AttributeError.